# How to validate textbox for emailid using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

How do you validate a Textbox field for valid email address using Jquery?

Please reply soon.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Pleas accept some answers to your other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    var emailaddressVal = $("#txtEmail").val();
    if (emailaddressVal == '') {
        $("#error").html("Please enter your email address.").css({ 'color': 'red' });
        return;
    }
    else if (!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {
        $("#error").html("Enter a valid email address.").css({ 'color': 'red' });
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use a plugin like this one:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

then you can do somethign like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
});
```

or this

```
$("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Email is a required field.",
            email: "Email - Invalid email address"
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Jimplode, can you send one example of rules for emailid validation.Thanks for the reply

Comment: how to validate that textbox will take emailid only.not any other text using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Check this plug-in out.

Not really worth it if you only want one validation though, in my opinion. So you might be better off with some REGEX validation for it.