# Checking for a valid email address

Tags: jquery, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate email address in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)
>   [Validate email with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778624/validate-email-with-jquery)

Currently I am using this in a contact form that I have built to check that the email field is not left blank

```
    var email = $("input#email").val();  
            if (email == "") {  
            $("label#email_error").show();  
            $("input#email").focus();  
        return false;  
        }
```

How can I run a check that the email input field contains an @ character?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778624/validate-email-with-jquery) and [How to validate textbox for emailid using JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277513/how-to-validate-textbox-for-emailid-using-jquery).

Answer (score 1):

Change `if (email == "") {` to `if (!(email.indexOf('@') > 0)) {`. This will make sure that:

- The string contains `@`.
- The `@` is not the first character.
- The string is not empty.

Example:

```
var email = $("input#email").val();
if (!(email.indexOf('@') > 0)) {
    $("label#email_error").show();
    $("input#email").focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. In fact, the form submitted when the field was blank.

Comment: I realize the logic error now. It needs to be NOT'd. Modified answer, please try again and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I run a check that the email input field contains an @ character?

Simple enough:

```
if(email.indexOf('@') == -1)
{
    /* no @ in the string */
}
```

This is *not* enough to validate an email address, however. See the previous question: [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: This worked but you're right, something more robust is better.